# C library function to perform sort

Tags: c, sorting

Is there any library function available in C standard library to do sort?

Comment: @Alexandru, the whole point of SO is to be a place for *all* programming-related question, of *any* skill level. Where do you think Google should direct people to when they use that query of yours? The powers that be want it to come *here* - when SO is the top Google link for that query, our job is done.

Comment: My original code was lazy and probably alot different then what you would have found with a Google search.  However after all of the community input you have an example of a good implementation of how to use qsort.

Comment: @paxdiablo: if that's the case, they might as well simply host the standard lib documentation - I doubt this question will add anything above that canonical reference, here.  For some complex cases, perhaps - but just to find a basic function?

Comment: Even questions like this contribute to the eventual completeness of SO as a helpful database for stuck coders.

Comment: Also in many cases people don't know what to search for.  If you know that c has a sort function named qsort() documentation is easily accessible, however if you don't know what to look for what resource should one use.

Answer (score 150):

`qsort()` is the function you're looking for. You call it with a pointer to your array of data, the number of elements in that array, the size of each element and a comparison function.

It does its magic and your array is sorted in-place. An example follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2) 
{
    int f = *((int*)elem1);
    int s = *((int*)elem2);
    if (f > s) return  1;
    if (f < s) return -1;
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int x[] = {4,5,2,3,1,0,9,8,6,7};

    qsort (x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x), sizeof(*x), comp);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        printf ("%d ", x[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should use sizeof(*x) in case you ever change the type in future but +1 for providing a sample.

Comment: Good point, @Thomas, I got rid of that non-standard monstrosity :-)

Comment: In general case, an attempt to compare ints by subtracting one from another will result in overflow. It's better to stay away from that bad habit from the very beginning. Use `return (f > s) - (f < s);`

Comment: You might also use `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])` in case your array size ever changes. You might also abstract that away into a macro, and you might change the declaration to `x[] =` so that the size can change without breaking your code. And for the final pedantry, you should never use an `int` to index arrays - that's what `size_t` is invented for.

Comment: I did write this as a quick example only but thank for the commentary non the less.

Comment: Okay, changed as per most suggestions. I draw the line, @ChrisL, at needing size_t since my arrays never get that big :-) And, @AndreyT, clever though that hack is, I prefer my code to be readable :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: That "hack" is a well-established idiom. Any programmer worth his salt recognizes it immediately. It has no negative effects on readability.

Comment: @paxdiablo :Only using sizeof(*x) won't work if you are changing the type, you have to modify the compare function accordingly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with indexing arrays using `int` (or `char` for that matter).  The *size* of an array, however, should be a `size_t`.

Comment: I wrote a very simple version of quicksort and the internal library one turned out to be slower

Comment: that's possible the standard library implementations are meant to solve general problems.  If you have more information about a problem you can special case and always outperform.

Comment: C doesn't support overloading so there's nothing wrong with the assumption that sizeof(*x) will always be int as you've already made it in the comp function.

Comment: Be aware that `qsort()` is not stable.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 why do you saw `qsort()` is not stable?

Comment: @JAamish ISO C99 Standard N1256, in "7.20.5.2 The `qsort` function" Point 4 "If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting sorted array is unspecified."

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 thanks for pointing to the spec.. :) It is very interesting and important point about qsort.. this really helps

Answer (score 71):

C/C++ standard library `<stdlib.h>` contains `qsort` function.

This is not the best quick sort implementation in the world but it fast enough and VERY
EASY to be used... the formal syntax of qsort  is:

```
qsort(<arrayname>,<size>,sizeof(<elementsize>),compare_function);
```

The only thing that you need to implement is the compare_function, which takes in two
arguments of type "const void", which can be cast to appropriate data structure, and then
return one of these three values:

- negative, if a should be before b
- 0, if a equal to b
- positive, if a should be after b

**1. Comparing a list of integers**:

simply cast a and b to integers
if `x < y`,`x-y` is negative, `x == y`, `x-y = 0`, `x > y`, `x-y` is positive
`x-y` is a shortcut way to do it :)
reverse `*x - *y` to `*y - *x` for sorting in decreasing/reverse order

```
int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) {
int *x = (int *) a;
int *y = (int *) b;
return *x - *y;
}
```

**2. Comparing a list of strings**:

For comparing string, you need `strcmp` function inside `<string.h>` lib.
`strcmp` will by default return -ve,0,ve appropriately... to sort in reverse order, just reverse the sign returned by strcmp

```
#include <string.h>
int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) {
return (strcmp((char *)a,(char *)b));
}
```

**3. Comparing floating point numbers**:

```
int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) {
double *x = (double *) a;
double *y = (double *) b;
// return *x - *y; // this is WRONG...
if (*x < *y) return -1;
else if (*x > *y) return 1; return 0;
}
```

**4. Comparing records based on a key**:

Sometimes you need to sort a more complex stuffs, such as record. Here is the simplest
way to do it using `qsort` library.

```
typedef struct {
int key;
double value;
} the_record;

int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) {
the_record *x = (the_record *) a;
the_record *y = (the_record *) b;
return x->key - y->key;
}
```

Comment: A pretty good answer, but the explanation of the return value of the compare function is backwards.  Also, in some of the examples, you're doing the x-y trick, which can give faulty results (and is less obvious than a simple comparison).

Comment: Well,as far as I am concerned now .. this works for every contest ;)

Comment: The x-y trick doesn't work if the difference between x and y is greater than the largest representable int. So it is fine when comparing two positive numbers, but will fail comparing, eg, INT_MAX and -10. Upvoted though because I like all the examples of sorting very different types.

Comment: As well as the overflow problem in both the integer comparator and the key comparator functions, the string compare function is incorrect.   When sorting an array of `int`, the values passed to the comparator are both `int *` disguised as `void *`.  When sorting an array of `char *`, therefore, the values passed to the comparator are both `char **` disguised as `void *`.  Therefore, the correct code needs to be: `int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) { return (strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b)); }`.

Comment: For integer comparisons that are overflow resistant, consider `if (x > y) return +1; else if (x < y) return -1; else return 0;`, or if you want a simple expression, then `return (x > y) - (x < y);`. This always evaluates two comparisons at the C level, but the optimizer might be able to avoid that. Subtraction doesn't work on unsigned values. The first version works well when you are dealing with a series of comparison — comparing 2 integer members of a structure first, and if they're equal, then two doubles, then two strings, etc. There's more than one way to do it, in C as well as Perl.

Comment: The second argument is not exactly size, but count.

Answer (score 11):

For sure:  `qsort()` is an implementation of a sort (not necessarily quicksort as its name might suggest).

Try man 3 qsort or have a read at http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

Comment: `qsort` does not have to be implemented using Quicksort.

Answer (score 8):

While not in the standard library exactly, https://github.com/swenson/sort has just two header files you can include to get access to a wide range of incredibly fast sorting routings, like so:

```c
#define SORT_NAME int64
#define SORT_TYPE int64_t
#define SORT_CMP(x, y) ((x) - (y))
#include "sort.h"
/* You now have access to int64_quick_sort, int64_tim_sort, etc., e.g., */
int64_quick_sort(arr, 128); /* Assumes you have some int *arr or int arr[128]; */
```

This should be at least twice as fast as the standard library `qsort`, since it doesn't use function pointers, and has many other sorting algorithm options to choose from.

It's in C89, so should work in basically every C compiler.

Answer (score 5):

try `qsort` in stdlib.h.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for `qsort`.
`qsort` function is the implementation of quicksort algorithm found in `stdlib.h` in `C/C++`.

Here is the syntax to call `qsort` function:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

***List of arguments:***
**base**: pointer to the first element or base address of the array 
**nmemb**: number of elements in the array 
**size**: size in bytes of each element 
**compar**: a function that compares two elements

Here is a code example which uses `qsort` to sort an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr[] = { 33, 12, 6, 2, 76 };

// compare function, compares two elements
int compare (const void * num1, const void * num2) {
   if(*(int*)num1 > *(int*)num2)
    return 1;
   else
    return -1;
}

int main () {
   int i;

   printf("Before sorting the array: \n");
   for( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
   // calling qsort
   qsort(arr, 5, sizeof(int), compare);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the array: \n");
   for( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
  
   return 0;
}
```

You can type `man 3 qsort` in Linux/Mac terminal to get a detailed info about `qsort`.
[Link to qsort man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3p.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use `qsort()` in `<stdlib.h>`.

@paxdiablo
The `qsort()` function conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'').

Answer (score 3):

There are several C sorting functions available in `stdlib.h`. You can do `man 3 qsort` on a unix machine to get a listing of them but they include:

- heapsort
- quicksort
- mergesort

Comment: heapsort and mergesort are not in the standard.

Comment: Neither is quicksort. The standard does not mandate which algorithm is used.

Answer (score 0):

GNU qsort source in stdlib shows that it is quicksort.