# Sorting an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, qsort

I have an assignment I've been working on for a few hours now, and I can't seem to get it quite right. The assignment is to take a random number of names (from stdin), sort them, and then output them in alphabetical order. I can't find any sites online that handle this kind of sorting specifically, and have had no luck trying to implement qsort() into my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
} 

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char *input[] = {" "};
     char temp[20][20];
     int i = 0;
     int num = 0;
     int place = 0;
     int stringlen = sizeof(temp) / sizeof(char);


          printf("How many names would you like to enter? ");
          scanf("%d", &num);

          while (place < num)
          {
                printf("Please input a name(first only): ");
                scanf("%s", input[place]);
                printf("The name you entered is: ");
                printf("%s\n", input[place]);

                place++;
          }
          //qsort(temp, stringlen, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);      <-- just an idea I was messing with
          qsort(input, stringlen, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);

          printf("Names:\n");

          for(i=0; i<place; i++)
               printf("%s\n", input[i]);



          system("PAUSE");
          return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

The main problem is, when I go to output my code, I cannot use the char *input variable because of how its declared. The temp[] will display, but will not be sorted by qsort because it is not declared as a pointer. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787996/c-library-function-to-do-sort/1788048#1788048

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't declare your input array like that.  Since you know how many the user requires, you can dynamically allocate the array:

```
char **input = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
```

Likewise, when you read your strings in, they need somewhere to go.  Simply passing an uninitialized pointer to `scanf` is not okay.  I suggest you define the maximum length of a name and have a temporary buffer for reading it:

```
const size_t MAX_NAME = 50;
char name[MAX_NAME];

...

for( i = 0; i < num; i++ )
{
    printf("Please input a name(first only): ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    input[i] = strdup(name);
}
```

[Note this does not prevent the user from overflowing the 'name' buffer.  I used `scanf` for illustrative purposes only]

You seem to be passing the wrong array length to `qsort`.  Try this:

```
  qsort(input, num, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);
```

When you are finished, you need to release memory for all the names and the array.

```
for( i = 0; i < num; i++ ) free(input[i]);
free(input);
```

> could you explain
>   the ** declarations throughout the code? I'm not sure what they're
>   used for, although I know the function for stringcmp is a widely used
>   algorithm, I have no idea how it works; I'm thrown off by the double
>   de-reference markers.

Yep, in the case where I used it, I am telling C that to get a single character, I have to dereference a pointer twice.  When you index a pointer, it's dereferencing.  So I allocated an array by requesting a block of memory containing `num * sizeof(char*)` bytes.  Because I assigned that pointer to a `char**`, the compiler knows that I am pointing to a chunk of memory that contains `char*` values.

If I ask for `input[0]` (this is the same as `*input`) it should look at the very start of that memory and pull out enough bytes to form a `char*`.  When I ask for `input[1]`, it skips past those bytes and pulls out the next bunch of bytes that form a `char*`.  Etc...  Likewise, when I index a `char*`, I am pulling out single characters.

In your `stringcmp` function, you have the following situation.  You passed a `void*` pointer to `qsort` so it doesn't actually know the size of the data values stored in your array.  That's why you have to pass both the array length AND the size of a single element.  So `qsort` just blindly rips through this arbitrary-length array of arbitrary-sized values and fires off memory addresses that ought to contain your data for comparison.  Because `qsort` doesn't know anything else about your array elements except where they are located, it just uses `void*`.

But YOU know that those pointers are going to be the memory addresses of two of your array elements, and that your array elements are `char*`.  So you need the address of a `char*` (hence you cast the pointers to `char**`).  Now you need to dereference these pointers when you call `strcmp()` because that function requires a `char*` (ie a value that points directly to the memory containing your string characters).  That is why you use the `*` in `strcmp(*ia, *ib)`.

Comment: Okay. I've got this part working for now. But for displaying the output, I'm assuming you can't just index into input?

Comment: You sure can.  Look, both my loops index into `input`.  By indexing it, you get a `char*` at the position requested by the index.  That `char*` points to a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you don't mind me asking, could you explain the ** declarations throughout the code? I'm not sure what they're used for, although I know the function for stringcmp is a widely used algorithm, I have no idea how it works; I'm thrown off by the double de-reference markers. If not, no worries!

Comment: No worries, I have edited my answer and tried to explain.  I hope it makes sense =)

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to fix your program is to declare `input` as an array of pointers, like this:

```
char *input[20];
```

When you read names in, use `tmp[place]` for your buffer, and store the pointer into `input`, like this:

```
scanf("%19s", tmp[place]);
input[place] = tmp[place];
```

Now sorting the `input` should work fine.

This has a limitation of being limited to 20 lines of 20 characters max. If you learned about `malloc` in the class, you should be able to fix that by allocating your strings and the string array dynamically.