# How to find the Highest mark for giving three marks?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
int main () 
{ 
        printf("Enter the Physics ,Chemistry and Maths Marks"); 
        int mark[3]= {40,50,10};
        int s[3];
        int i; 
        int sum = 0, highest = 0; 
        clrscr(); 
        for (i = 0; i < ; i++) 
             { 
                sum += mark[i]; 
                if (mark[i] > highest) 
                        highest = mark[i]; 
             } 

        printf("The Highest Mark is %d: \n", highest); 
        getch(); 

    return 0; 

}
```

its working fine, I need to give a input dynamically and get the output

How to do that?

```
Enter the Marks : 30 20 10
output: 30
```

Comment: Hint: Use `scanf` to get input. BTW, That code won't compile and has some unused variables. Also, why do you have `clrscr()` *after* the first `printf`?

Comment: yes i will remove that unused variable and clrscr() .how to get the input array it shows wrong max value

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> 
 #include<conio.h>
int main () 
{ 
     clrscr();
        printf("Enter the Physics ,Chemistry and Maths Marks"); 
        int mark[3];
  mark[3]=scanf ("%d",mark[3]);
        int i; 
        int sum = 0, highest = 0; 
    
        for (i = 0; i < ; i++) 
             { 
                sum += mark[i]; 
                if (mark[i] > highest) 
                        highest = mark[i]; 
             } 
         
        printf("The Highest Mark is %d: \n", highest); 
        getch(); 
        return 0; 
}`

Comment: Please add the code into the question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32422634/edit). Also, `for (i = 0; i < ; i++)` won't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I obtain which of this variables have the highest value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409701/how-can-i-obtain-which-of-this-variables-have-the-highest-value)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int mark[3];
mark[3] = scanf("%d",mark[3]);
```

is wrong because of several reasons. It seems that you don't know how to use `scanf` properly. It should be

```
int mark[3];
scanf("%d", &mark[0]);
scanf("%d", &mark[1]);
scanf("%d", &mark[2]); /* Get each number from stdin and store it in the address of the variable given */
```

or better

```
int mark[3];
scanf("%d %d %d", &mark[0], &mark[1], &mark[2]);
```

or even better

```
int mark[3], i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) /* Loop 3 times */
{
    scanf("%d", &mark[i]);
}
```

Comment: if i giving that it shows wrong output value, It will Always shows 12803 as output

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else. Please post the **exact** code and the error and/or warning messages that you get. Currently,neither the code in the question nor the code in the comment compiles. You should also include your input and the output you get along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers from the input using `scanf()` and then find the highest number using `fmax()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int mark[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    int highest = 0;

    printf("Enter the Marks\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &mark[i]);
        highest = fmax(highest, mark[i]);
    }

    printf("The Highest Mark is %d: \n", highest);
}
```