# Sorting with a compare function

Tags: javascript, sorting

So I understand that given an array, you can sort it using a custom compare function.

So something like the following in Javascript:

```
var arr = [5,4,3,6,7,2];
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    else if (a > b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});
```

So my friend was saying that I don't need to return 0 to sort the list for this scenario. Furthermore, he says that we can return from `[true,false]` instead of returning from `[-1,0,1]`. Is that true?
I was trying to find a counterexample to his claim, but I could not. I can't imagine a case where the array isn't sorted properly using his code.

Here's the example that my friend gave:

```
var arr = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
});
```

Is it good practice to return from a range of `[-1,0,1]`? What is the necessity when the integers are comparable? I've noticed that this is the case across a multitude of programming languages and not just javascript. Like this example in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791064/198348).

Comment: `});` (twice!) looks wrong.

Comment: According to the documentation, your friend is wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Note that they don't have to be just `[-1, 0, 1]`, they can be any negative, 0, or any positive value. This allows you to do `return a - b;`.

Comment: What @Phil said, and you should use the keyword `var` unless you want `arr` to be global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell your friend they are definitely wrong.

```
[0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3].sort(function(a, b) { return a > b })

-> [2, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not good practice, you should follow the language specification, which says that the comparison function should return a positive value when the first element is greater than the second, a negative value when the first element is lower than the second, and 0 if they're equivalent.

What you're doing might work in some implementations, but won't be portable. Returning `true` and `false` is likely to result in them being coerced to `1` and `0`, respectively. And some sorting algorithms only need to know whether element A is greater than element B (for instance, the Common Lisp language specifies its `SORT` function to take a boolean comparison function, so it obviously requires that the implementation use such an algorithm), so the desired result may be obtained. But if an implementation depends on tri-state logic, it won't work -- returning `false` or `0` will make it think that those elements are equivalent, and it may not order them properly.