# How to implement Suffix array in c

Tags: suffix-array

However its easy to get the implementation using C++ as there is built-in `Sort()` function in algorithm header file.
I have gone through the both naive method and O(nlogn) methods of forming the array. In both the cases the `sort()` function is used for sorting the suffixes.

Is there any good method in C?

Comment: Have a look at the concept of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please provide an example with a simple input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you googled "sort c" and found NOTHING?  I see several helpful links when I do that.  For example, have a look at this question and its answers: [C library function to do sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787996/c-library-function-to-do-sort). Also the Wikipedia article on suffix arrays gives good overview of methods of constructing suffix arrays: O(N) method of constructing a suffix tree and then the suffix array, O(N^2 log N) method of sorting the suffixes (sorting requires O(N log N) comparisons, and each comparison is O(N), so the total time is O(N^2 log N)), and other advanced methods.  The Wikipedia article also points to a few implementations in Java, C/C++ etc.

Comment: Maybe a suffix array is not a 1D vector, but rather a 2D matrix? That would require some specialized kind of sorting.

Comment: Thanks @Agostino. I picked on only the point that they were able to use standard C++ Sort, but couldn't find a C equivalent. I could have added just a comment, but not enough reputation, so added an answer. Anyway, we can only wait for SSCCE.