# How to find the average, highest score, second highest score, and the lowest score in array form?

Tags: c

I'm a newbie to coding in C and I'm trying to get the average of the inputted array but for some reason it's giving me random numbers for the output.

How can I fix this? And while I'm here, how to find the highest score, second highest score, and the lowest score of the inputted array? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int i, T, sum = 0, avg;
    char name[T];
    int score[T];
    
    printf("Input number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &T);
    
    for(i = 1; i <= T; i++){
    printf("Input student names-%d: ", i);
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Input student scores-%d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", score);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= T; i++){
    sum = sum + score[i];
    avg = sum / T;
    }

    printf("Average score = %d", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to store user input score into the array elements. You are only storing in the 0 th index for all the students. So, during average calculation the rest contains garbage value. Also, `score[T]` and `name[T]` isn't what you expect

Comment: You start over, do al the exercises up to this point, enable compiler warnings, and you pay extra attention in the chapter about arrays, and the chapter about conditional statements (`if` to be precise). You are not ready for this exercise, because you are making basic mistakes in this code. That means you have advanced through subjects you don't yet understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting the array first? Then the highest score will be in `sorted[0]`, the next highest will be in `sorted[1]`, etc. (In case you wanted to exclude draws, you can also compare `sorted[1]` with `sorted[0]` first if it is indeed lower instead of equal, in a `while` loop to skip all equals). Sorting wouldn't mess the average, so you can calculate the average either before or after sorting.
For how to sort in C, you might take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787996/c-library-function-to-perform-sort).